# When to use traits, as opposed to inheritance and composition?

Tags: object-oriented-design

There are three common ways, AFAIK, to implement reusability when it comes to OOP

1. Inheritance : usually to represent is-a relationship (a duck is-a bird)
2. Composition: usually to represent has-a relationship (a car has-a engine)
3. Traits (e.g. the trait keyword in PHP) : ...not really sure about this

While it looks to me that traits can implement both has-a and is-a relationships, I am not really sure what kind of modelling it was intended for. What kind of situations were traits designed for?

Comment: You may explain a bit more about traits, but could traits just be another word for compositions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)

Comment: I'd really like to know why as well. Haven't used them once.

Comment: this may help clarify things: is "composition" better described as "constructor dependency injection"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Traits are another way to do composition.  Think of them as a way to compose all the parts of a class at compile time (or JIT compile time), assembling the concrete implementations of the parts you will need.

Basically, you want to use traits when you find yourself making classes with different combinations of features.  This situation comes up most often for people writing flexible libraries for others to consume.  For example, here's the declaration of a unit test class I wrote recently using [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/):

```scala
class TestMyClass
  extends WordSpecLike
  with Matchers
  with MyCustomTrait
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with BeforeAndAfterEach
  with ScalaFutures
```

Unit test frameworks have a *ton* of different configuration options, and every team has different preferences about how they want to do things.  By putting the options into traits (which are mixed in using `with` in Scala), ScalaTest can offer all those options without having to create class names like `WordSpecLikeWithMatchersAndFutures`, or a ton of runtime boolean flags like `WordSpecLike(enableFutures, enableMatchers, ...)`.  This makes it easy to follow the [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).  You can add new features, and new combinations of features, simply by adding a new trait.  It also makes it easier to follow the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), because you can easily put functions not universally needed into a trait.

Traits are also a good way to put common code into several classes that do not make sense to share an inheritance hierarchy.  Inheritance is a very tightly-coupled relationship, and you shouldn't pay that cost if you can help it.  Traits are a much more loosely-coupled relationship.  In my example above, I used `MyCustomTrait` to easily share a mock database implementation between several otherwise unrelated test classes.

Dependency injection achieves many of the same goals, but at runtime based on user input instead of at compile time based on programmer input.  Traits are also intended more for dependencies that are semantically part of the same class.  You're sort of assembling the parts of one class rather than making calls out to other classes with other responsibilities.

Dependency injection *frameworks* achieve many of the same goals at compile time based on programmer input, but are largely a workaround for programming languages without proper trait support.  Traits bring these dependencies into the realm of the compiler's type checker, with cleaner syntax, with a simpler build process, that makes a more clear distinction between compile-time and runtime dependencies.

Comment: Hi, this is a great answer. May I ask how do decide when to use traits, and when to use dependency injection. which seems to be achieve the same.

Comment: Astute observation.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. I'm curious about your answer about traits being like composition @KarlBielefeldt. Your class can be used wherever that trait is needed, and you would still suffer from the same fragility as with a regular interface. So it seems closer to subtyping and inheritance, no? I'm also unsure how it's similar to DI...if you have various classes defined that extend traits, then aren't those concrete dependencies defined wherever in the hierarchy that class is defined, rather than at an top / entry point of the code? Thanks!

Comment: Traits *can* be used just like interfaces, for their inheritance properties, but that's not what makes them unique. The `with` operator is what differentiates them, and `with` is a composition operation. And yes, traits replace DI without needing to be defined at the entry point of the code. That's one of the things that makes them preferable in my opinion.

Comment: I use traits to satisfy the requirements of an interface, and to reduce code duplication. I test for implementation of an interface, rather than use of a trait at runtime, though.